# Page views and Lightning Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, governorlimits, documentation, lightning-community

I can't seem to find any documentation on the usage of page views with lightning and especially with communities. Is there a clear Salesforce provided page with what count and what doesn't count as a page view. For example if I need to make a call from my component to his apex controller or if I navigate from one component to another ?

Thanks.

Comment: The [Google Analytics™ for Salesforce Communities Dashboard package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_g_a_dashboards_desc.htm&type=5) seems like a good starting point.  Not sure when it was released, but probably well after this question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

As part of Lightning communities documentation you can use google analytics to track page hits,views by user and object.

Below link has more information on the same

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_networks_google_analytics_for_self_service.htm

I havent tried it but from the information provided seems it can provide lot of insights on page hits,views by users.

Answer (score 0):

For communities you can check `Community Management Package for Communities` app on the appexchange. You have 2 versions, one with chatter, and other without.

This app creates the reports of pageviews, activity of topics, feed, and many other things.

Link:

[Spring '17 Salesforce Community Management Package for Communities with Chatter](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5XHsEAN)